# How to fetch the vsrx IP using softlayer IP

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, juniper

I am able to fetch the vsrx (public/private/mgmt) IP using getNetworkGateways service using 
curl -g https://xxxx:xx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[id,name,networkSpace,status.name,publicIpAddress,memberCount]

but I am not getting the vsrx configuration IP. Vsrx is the Juniper based Gateway Appliance in the IBM Cloud infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try the request adding [SoftLayer_Network_Gateway](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/) properties into the mask and adding filter.
You can use the following rest api call to retrieve gateways details.

```
Method: GET 
https://[username]:[apikey]api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[id,name,networkSpace,status.name,privateIpAddress.ipAddress,publicIpAddress.ipAddress,publicIpv6Address.ipAddress,memberCount]]&objectFilter={"networkGateways":{"members":{"hardware":{"operatingSystem":{"softwareDescription":{"manufacturer":{"operation":"Juniper"}}}}}}}
```

Also ,you can to try using the [SoftLayer_Network_Gateway::getObject](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/getObject/) method as below:

```
Method: GET 
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[gatewayId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,name,privateIpAddress.ipAddress,publicIpAddress.ipAddress,publicIpv6Address.ipAddress]
```

You will get a response like this

```
{
    "id": 111111,
    "name": "test-vsrx",
    "privateIpAddress": {
        "ipAddress": "privateIp"
    },
    "publicIpAddress": {
        "ipAddress": "publicIp"
    },
    "publicIpv6Address": {
        "ipAddress": "publicIpv6"
    }
}
```

You can check the link below may be it help you with performing vSRX basics:
[IBM Cloud Juniper vSRX Standard](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/vsrx/vsrx-basics.html#performing-vsrx-basics)